# JFreeChart determine the dimensions of grid

Tags: java, grid, jfreechart

How to determine the unit dimensions of a grid in xyplot in `JFreeChart`?
I want to determine the value of length and breadth of the grid with respective to the ranges of the x and y axis

Comment: Why? `JFreeChart` scales to fill the preferred size of the enclosing container, e.g. `ChartPanel`.

Comment: i want to draw a circle within 1 grid. So i would like to know the width and height of the grid

Comment: What do you mean by grid? As in gridlines?

Comment: You can set the chart's preferred size to have a 1:1 aspect ratio and [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089206/jfree-chart-mouse-drag-to-zoom) may be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values can be obtained using the plot.getDomainAxis.getTickUnit().getSize() and similarly for rangeAxis.