# Jfree chart Mouse Drag to Zoom

Tags: java, mouseevent, jfreechart

How to modify mouseDragged event of ChartPanel such that I want to do some processing before/after the zooming is done? 
I have the following chartPanel,

```
JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(
                "Demo", JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT,plot, true);
ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
```

Whenever the mouse is dragged, I want to call my function before/ after the mouseDragged() is called. How to do this ?

```
chartPanel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

i am unable to see `super.mouseDragged(e)`.
how to invoke my function after the chart is zoomed. Basically what i want to do is after the chart is zoomed, I want to get the range of x and y coordinates and add a suitable `XYAnnotation`. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override [`mouseDragged()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#mouseDragged%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) in `org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel` and do your processing before or after `super.mouseDragged(e)`.

Addendum: [`MouseMotionAdapter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionAdapter.html) may be a convenient alternative:

```
chartPanel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // process before
        super.mouseDragged(e);
        // process after
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you see the question above. I have modified it

Comment: I've outlined an approach above.